# How to add the wildcard to any user or database using phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I add wildcard to any database and it's user using phpmyadmin so it will accept both connections from local and WAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would strongly caution what level of access you assign to databases and users without fully understanding the security implications of doing so!**

While granting users limited access to certain databases using wildcard hosts is generally okay and many times is necessary, granting unrestricted or high-level access opens your system to security exploits like SQL and PHP injection attacks.

---

In phpMyAdmin, click on the Users tab; find the user account you wish to edit and click on "Edit Privileges" link. In the dialog that opens, locate the "Change Login Information / Copy User" field. In the "Host" field, select "Any" from the pop-up menu or add `%` to the field - this sets the wildcard to allow that user access to the database from any IP or host.

Database privileges are assigned per-user, per database. To give a user access to particular databases, you can assign them in the same dialog as above under the "Database-specific privileges" fields. A single user can have access to multiple databases with unique permissions on each database.